# Referring to parent

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have a grid panel which contains a function definition too:

```
    var s_grid= new Ext.grid.GridPanel ({
    ...
    ......
    addRow:function(organizationId,name,coreNumber) {
        ........
        Ext.getCmp("s_grid").getView().focusRow(i);
        .......
  }
 });
```

Is there a better way for the function object to refer to its parent;rather than doing a iteration over the entire Ext domian as in the code?
I am using ExtJs 3.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the function is defined in your grid configuration, the grid will be the function's scope anyway, so you should be able to access it using `this`:

```
this.getView().focusRow(i);
```